# Loop until specific input

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

I need to write a program that will:

1. ask for a starting account balance;
2. ask me to enter my withdrawal amount and loop this question until I enter a value of 0; and
3. tell me the account balance – either positive or negative.

Main area where I am having problems: 2. – the withdrawal until loop.

Example output:

```
What is your starting balance: $ 1000.00
What is your withdrawal amount: $ 250.00
What is your withdrawal amount: $ 295.00
What is your withdrawal amount: $ 187.50
What is your withdrawal amount: $ 0
Your account balance is: $267.50
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Homework questions, and this looks like homework, are not valid questions.  I would recommend something like reddit.com/r/learnpython or similar mediums.  Voting to close as question is too abstract or not a question.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus - There is no source code at this time as I deleted what I was working on in a fit of rage (three hours of frustration) – I feel dumb now as I did have somewhat working set of code. Thank you for the links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3

amt = int(input("What is your starting balance: $"))
while(True):
    i = int(input("What is your withdrawal amount: $"))
    if(i == 0):
        break
    else:
        amt -= i

print("Your account balance is:"+str(amt))
```

Comment: Don’t put parentheses around conditions in `while` and `if`.

Comment: Why `int()`? `float()` would make more sense. Also, you should make use of the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to make sure that two decimal digits will always be printed.

Comment: @Isuru Madusanka - thank you, I will give your suggestion a try.